# Django Rest Framework, generic RetrieveAPIView view for a model instance method.

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have been using Django REST Framework with generic update and retrieve views for my project in a fairly standard fashion.

Now I would like to serve some json based on a models instance method.

Is it considered good / bad practice to use the RetrieveAPIView for this (and serialize the data in a custom serialzer class)?